# How to narrow a type using typeof keyword?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Students {
    [key:string]: (Student | undefined);
}

interface Student {
    age: string;
}

function something (students:Students, student_name:string) {
    let student:Student;

    if (typeof students[student_name] !== 'undefined')
        student = students[student_name]; // Type 'Student | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Student'.
    else
        return;
}
```

I often face that situation. Of course, I can use *as Student*. But, I wanna know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually TypeScript will use [control-flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to automatically narrow the type of a value once you have done a check on it.  But the problem you're running into is the fact that this narrowing does not happen with bracket-style property accesses (see [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530)) like `students[student_name]`.  It was addressed for *literal* index types (see [microsoft/TypeScript#26424](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26424)) such as `students["Alice"]`, equivalent to `students.Alice`... but to make it work with `string` would apparently degrade the compiler performance too much.

The workaround here is to perform the index access just once, and assign the result to a new variable.  Then when you check that variable, the control flow analysis should narrow as you want:

```
function something(students: Students, student_name: string) {      
  let student: Student;      
  const maybeStudent = students[student_name]; // Student | undefined
  if (typeof maybeStudent !== 'undefined')
    student = maybeStudent; // okay, maybeStudent narrowed to Student in check
  else
    return;
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgK4BMLgM7IDeAsAFDIXIDaA1hAJ4BcyeYUoA5gLrMAU62XGGQAfZBhA4YoCFgCUAbjIBfMmVCRYiFAJzgiZSsjgcIzVuxAclpVaTIwJCMMAD2IFq4C2EMAAtOXlZBfGZdITwAGhZMPTAAfRA4H3M2TjkDckoAG18YkLAw2KEbIwR3VmQvOHoAIwhw-QBefLi8KmC4xOSILgVkAHoBtGL9MQkpGSxDSmAYZF4wegAHCFd56rqG0eEAQiaWgHIJiGkQWUO5GaMKTqFkFs36xrB+oeRXGhrop+2C5CSUCgrgA7rJkGBXCN-qBkAg-BAEDRrsgINk8BAUUYoL4MFAQDZlEA)

Answer (score 1):

you can read this; https://mariusschulz.com/blog/typescript-2-0-control-flow-based-type-analysis or this
https://www.google.com/search?q=typescript+flow+analysis&oq=typescript+flow+&aqs=chrome.5.69i57j69i60l3j0l2.6090j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

it's called flow analysis.