# Typescript: number | Array<number> can't do array operations

Tags: typescript

When having a type like this, I can't manage to do array operations even when I check for `tyepof` before doing them:

```js
type Demo = {
    [countryName: string]: number | Array<number>
}
```

I'm forced to use `as number` and create as many temporal variables as I need.
This is a simplified example but it can get quite ugly:
[Playground reproduction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhC2B7KBeKBvAsAKCnqA2gMaICuAdsAE4gByAhvBAFxQDO1AluQOYC6rcqXgAjCFSgAfKAEEqVeiAA8Q0eIB8OAL44cAN3oSSFLhDbM4SVBhz4oAcjZh63e6wAMAGlv57nYPQANiBuUABMXj549jzi8PTkIawEXlAAjJ7hfNoA3LrYBhLAiAGBgsJiEmjuedgAZogSABSFUMaUNFDcbWQdnGYAlDa4+Jx1TaCQiHU9JlT9bMS91CB8qChoAESqlZsDWCN2eMWlUADUaO2mi1c0a-RsUDvitXY6h1AQgWwQB0f4rWA8DAAGFlvMzNZbgslnNVlAHrJ5IoVBUNK9-lAGlQmoEIMAutYal0lEDQeCFgA6PG8YAACxyXTOZ32UUxxxKQXOlwpZlhHXhiOeVAx-3eb20OCAA)

```js
var countries:Demo = {
    'spain': 0,
    'italy': 20,
    'germany': [0, 1, 2]
};

var total: number = 0;
for (var country in countries) {
    if(typeof countries[country] === "number"){  //<--- useless?
        total += countries[country] as number;   // forced to use it
    }
    else{
        var tmpCountries = countries[country] as Array<number>;  //<--- forced tmp variable
        for(let i = 0; i<tmpCountries.length; i++){
            total += countries[country] as number;  //<-- again as number?
        }
    }
}
```

What's the way of dealing with this kind of objects for which we want to apply both number operations and array ones based on conditionals in our code?

Comment: TS doesn't like it if you just repeatedly use the same index. It doesn't maintain type narrowing for that case. You need a variable which can be as simple as `const c = countries[country]` at the start of the loop, so you just use one variable instead of indexing over and over again. Probably an easier option would be to directly loop over the values of the object: `for (var country of Object.values(countries))` (note the [`for..of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of))

Comment: Also, it's advisable to not use `var`. No need for that in TS - it would compile `const` or `let` to appropriate form anyway.

Comment: See the answer to [the question this duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54331666/how-to-narrow-a-type-using-typeof-keyword); the recommended workaround here is to save the value to a new variable where control flow analysis will now work, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nn6vaN) (ah, I see @VLAZ just said this).

Comment: @jcalz [Here is using `for..of` over just the object values](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhC2B7KBeKBvAsAKCnqA2gMaICuAdsAE4gByAhvBAFxQDO1AluQOYC6rcqXgAjCFSgAfKAEEqVeiAA8Q0eIB8OAL44cAN3oSSFLhDbM4SVBhz4oAcjZh63e6wAMAGlv57nYPQANiBuUABMXj549jzi8PTkIawEXlAAjJ7hfNoA3LrYBhLAiAGBgsJiEmjuedgAZogSABSFUMaUNFCIdVAA8iIAVhBEwAB0BoGkZk3tpmwAlPM2uPicdU2gkN1tZB0gqChoAESqlUfzWCt2eMWlUADUaLM0tXY6V1AQgWwQl9f4DSoTUCEGAUE41hq4KUzxAoxBvGAAAscuD7vcLlF-vhbkEHk9dtQQAROHxXtj3m9tDggA) just for completeness. But it's the same thing, just saves one line of declaring a variable in the loop.

Comment: [Alternatively...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhC2B7KBeKBvAsAKCnqA2gMaICuAdsAE4gByAhvBAFxQDO1AluQOYC6rcqXgAjCFSgAfKAEEqVeiAA8Q0eIB8OAL44cAN3oSSFLhDas4SVBhz4oAcjZh63e6wAMAGlv57nYPQANiBuUABMXj549jzi8PTkIawEXlAAjJ7hfNoA3LrYJOQc7MJyCiDWABR6gsJiVAR8AJSo6lB6AHRUEAAmpEQQlZX0mSItKG30UADUUGP5hcVkwGCkwNYA8iIAVhBEwB0GgaRmlcaUVJxmTV29-RAqdRpD9EREmXrjk28zUJVlig6nDYAJA1RaAH4SvBQeCoKxPpl3E0FogiohAhAOoFEDxKstVsAmkA)

Comment: @jcalz problem with that is that I can't modify objects by reference if I have to then save them in a different variable.

Comment: @VLAZ i can't replace `for in` for `of Object.values`. I need the key to assign it.

Comment: @Alvaro that is not part of the code you've shown here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
type Demo = {
    [countryName: string]: number | Array<number>
}

var countries:Demo = {
    'spain': 0,
    'italy': 20,
    'germany': [0, 1, 2]
};

var total: number = 0;
for (var country in countries) {
    let c = countries[country] // number | number[]
    if(typeof c === "number"){
        total +=c //number
    }
    else{
        // c number[]
        for(let i = 0; i<c.length; i++){
            total += c[i]
        }
    }
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhC2B7KBeKBvAsAKCnqA2gMaICuAdsAE4gByAhvBAFxQDO1AluQOYC6rcqXgAjCFSgAfKAEEqVeiAA8Q0eIB8OAL44cAN3oSSFLhDbM4SVBhz4oAcjZh63e6wAMAGlv57nYPQANiBuUABMXj549jzi8PTkIawEXlAAjJ7hfNoA3LrYBhLAiAGBgsJiEmjuedgAZogSABSFUMaUNFDcbWQdnGYAlDa4+IEQwG3W7aZsxL3UINkjeJx1TaCQiHWTKLtQAESqlfsDWMt2UMWlUADUKERRUDrnEIFsEGcX+A1UTWMTnGsNS6SiIADoxrxgAALHJdG43U6PL54K5BW5oIgEThLFFPR7PZ5AA)

Comment: ... although `as number` is not necessary after `c[i]`

Comment: Yeah, accidentally overlooked

Comment: So, if we have let's say, 7 variables doing this, we have to create 7 temporal variables?
`users.hobbies[type][availableDays]`, `users.tasks[type][availableDays]`,  `users.cars[type][availableDays]`....

Comment: Another issue I see with this, is that if my intent is to modify the value in the object (by reference) now this can't be done when assigning it to a variable.